# Envio de e-mail com PHPMailer com upload de arquivos

Tags: php, phpmailer

Olá, estou tentando resolver um problema. Estou usando o PHPMailer para fazer envios de e-mail após um formulário ser enviado. Esse envio de formulário funciona perfeitamente, todas as informações são enviadas, menos o arquivo que o usuário faz o upload.

**Código da função Mailer:**
`$nota= $_FILES['file'];` 
Aqui eu recupero o arquivo que o usuário faz upload no formulário. Abaixo disso vem toda a configuração do PHPMailer e etc.

**Código da parte do formulário que o usuário faz upload do arquivo:**

````
      <label for="nota">Nota fiscal</label>
      <input id="nota" type="file" name="file" placeholder="Nota fiscal[DOC ou PDF]">
    </div> ```




**Corpo da mensagem que é enviada:**
``` $body = "<b>Tipo de Registro:</b> $tipo  <br />
<b>Número de Série:</b>  $serie  <br />
<b>Data de compra:</b> $dt_compra  <br />
<b>Local de compra:</b> $local <br />
<b>Primeiro nome:</b> $primeironome <br />
<b>Último nome:</b> $ultimonome <br />
<b>E-mail:</b> $email <br />
<b>Telefone:</b> $telefone <br />
<b>País:</b> $pais <br />
<b>Endereço:</b> $endereco <br />
<b>Cidade:</b> $cidade <br />
<b>CEP:</b> $cep <br />
<b>Checkbox 1:</b> $check <br />
<b>Checkbox 2:</b> $check2 <br />
<b>Nota fiscal:</b> $nota";
  
$mail -> MsgHTML($body);
$mail -> AddAttachment($nota['tmp_name'], $nota['name']);
$a = $mail->Send(); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Tente verificar primeiro se o arquivo está vindo, e também se o form possui o atributo enctype="multipart/form-data".

Para verificar o arquivo:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 4)
{
    echo "arquivo não veio";
    exit();
}
```